# Error on contentType property application/xml works but application/json does not

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

This is my first question here. I have been searching Stack Overflow and other web resources but I cannot find a solid answer on what is required for FullCalendar to correctly accept a jQuery data property.

What I mean is that I have a web service that takes in a string for its required parameter. I am going to call this ***owner_email***.

The web service will take that parameter and return an array of `UserAssignments` to be rendered by FullCalendar.

I am having a problem with the actual passing of *owner_email* from jQuery/FullCalendar to the ASP.NET web service.

When I change contentType to 'application/xml' or comment it out, it returns an empty XML document (which I want at the moment) but when I change it back to 'application/json', an error occurs in json format. Any help is appreciated. Also, I would like to know what is required for an event to be put on FullCalendar.

Here is the code that I have done so far:
JavaScript:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ dayClick: function () { alert('a day was clicked!'); }, eventSources: [

// your event source { url: "WebService.asmx/displayUserAssignments", type: 'POST', data: { owner_email: 'test' }, processData: true, dataType: "json", contentType: 'application/json', color: 'yellow', // a non-ajax option textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option } // any other sources... ]
```

ASP.NET Snippet:

```
[WebMethod] [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] public UserAssignments[] displayUserAssignments(string owner_email) { int totalAssignments = 0; int current_index = 0; UserAssignments[] compiled_user_assignments; OracleConnection openedConnection = new OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BehemothConn"].ConnectionString); openedConnection.Open(); OracleCommand query = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM personal_assignments_view where owner_email = :input_email", openedConnection); OracleCommand numberOfRows = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from personal_assignments_view where owner_email = :input_email", openedConnection);

query.Parameters.Add(":input_email", OracleType.VarChar).Value = owner_email; numberOfRows.Parameters.Add(":input_email", OracleType.VarChar).Value = owner_email;

OracleDataReader returned_result = numberOfRows.ExecuteReader(); returned_result.Read(); totalAssignments = returned_result.GetInt32(0);

compiled_user_assignments = new UserAssignments[totalAssignments]; returned_result = query.ExecuteReader();

while (returned_result.Read()) { compiled_user_assignments[current_index] = new UserAssignments(); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].assignment_id = returned_result.GetInt32(0); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].owner_email = returned_result.GetString(1); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].assignment_name = returned_result.GetString(2); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].assignment_date = returned_result.GetOracleDateTime(3).Value.ToString("R"); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].assignment_description = returned_result.GetString(4); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].event_id = returned_result.GetInt32(5); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].week_day = returned_result.GetString(6); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].is_deleted = returned_result.GetString(7); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].start_time = returned_result.GetInt32(8); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].end_time = returned_result.GetInt32(9); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].is_completed = returned_result.GetString(10); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].pan_note_id = returned_result.GetInt32(11); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].pan_assign_id = returned_result.GetInt32(12); compiled_user_assignments[current_index].assignment_note = returned_result.GetString(13); current_index++; }

openedConnection.Close(); openedConnection.Dispose(); return compiled_user_assignments; }
```

UserAssignments class:

```
public class UserAssignments { public int assignment_id; public string owner_email; public string assignment_name; public string assignment_date; public string assignment_description; public int event_id; public string week_day; public string is_deleted; public int start_time; public int end_time; public string is_completed; public int pan_note_id; public int pan_assign_id; public string assignment_note;

public UserAssignments() { assignment_id = -1; owner_email = ""; assignment_name = ""; assignment_date = ""; assignment_description = ""; event_id = -1; week_day = ""; is_deleted = ""; start_time = -1; end_time = -1; is_completed = ""; pan_note_id = -1; pan_assign_id = -1; assignment_note = ""; } }
```

jQuery Error:

> {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: owner_email.","StackTrace":" at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32
>   depth)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String
>   input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext
>   context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(Http[...]

Comment: I have decided to use an xml return but how would I be able to format the output xml correctly for fullcalendar to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using >=.NET 3.5

The problem is :your data is not in correct JSON format. Try using JSON.stringify() and generate JSON data and if you don't want JSON2.js, try creating the data in appropriate JSON format manually.

Fullcalendar works well without much hacks if you are returning the array as JSON.

You will get same error message for start parameter.The problem lies in the fact that fullcalendar trying to append start and end parameters to your data,but the start and end is not in JSON format. So you have to goto fullcalendar.js and edit the following inside function _fetchEventSource(source, callback).

```
 $.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, {
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        success: function (events) {
                            events = events.d;
                           ............................
```

And in your webservice:-

*PS: Don't try to convert the list inside webservice to any format.Just return the List object. In the success event you have to get the JSON object from the 'key' named 'd',because in the new versions it encapsulates the object in the key named 'd' for ajax calls. So access it using that key.*

Your web service signature (example):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public List<Object> functionName(argumentList)
  { return ObjectList;}
```

[image: Webservice response captured using Firebug]
And if you are returning in XML,then you have to create your event[] object in appropriate format inside your javascript and call--> callback(events) for fullcalendar to display.

Comment: I was able to get XML working with FullCalendar. However, I did not realize that ASP.NET automatically creates separate elements instead of serializing it in one XML field. The `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Serialization` classes and the `XmlAttributeAttribute` property helped. Thanks for the help!
Sorry about not formatting it correctly. I was posting it from a phone.